# Get Highlighted Item From Editable Combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have Editable Combobx where I am adding Strings dynamically based on some logic instead of Combobox Items.

Now, I want to get Highlighted Item when combobox get focused, I know Combobox Item has IsHighlighted Property which can work but since I am adding as a string,

How Can I get Highlighted Sting from C# ? 
note that if I am trying to convert string to Combobox Item its erroring out!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

the code you have wrote get the selected item not the highlighted one !! this example will do the job for you :

note : in the code behind file you use the event gotfocus for the highlighted and lostfocus for to know when an item become "unhighlighted":

```
<ComboBox Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="128,107,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245">
            <ComboBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="GotFocusHandler" />
                    <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="LostFocusHandler" />
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.Resources>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Cat 1" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Cat 2" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Cat 3" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Cat 4" />
        </ComboBox>

private void GotFocusHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             string HighlightedText = (sender as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString(); 
             //do some thing
        }

        private void LostFocusHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string HighlightedText = (sender as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString();
            //do some thing
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I really understand what you are trying to do, but one way you could get the ComboBoxItem associated with the selected item would be to do something like this:

```
ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = (ComboBoxItem)DraggedComboBox2.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(DraggedComboBox2.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: Thank you xavier, I tried that but comboBoxItem is coming as null, any suggestion?